# Convert X11 Keysym to Key Name

Tags: c, x11

Is it possible to convert a keysym to key name like the output of `xmodmap -pke` using libX11 without having to parse the output of the `xmodmap`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [XKeysymToString](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XKeysymToString.html) function.